# floating <thead> in an overflow hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've made a table with a fixed header that stops when it reaches the bottom of my table. which i put into a **div** with `overflow: hidden;`. I kind of got everything to work, but not 100% to my liking.

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="tableWithFloatingHeader">
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>table1 col header</th>
       <th>table1 col header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>table1 col header2</th>
       <th>table1 col header2</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

       .............

   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

problem is:

1. i can't seem to get everything in the `<thead>` to scroll down too.
       only the 1st row does (the first `<tr>`).
2. **ONLY** the `<th>` visible in the div should be seen when
       scrolling down.
3. How do i position my controllers right beside the div? On a bigger
   monitor, it's position is way off (because of this `'left': '20px'`)

here is a link to my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ya7dl/2/)

and here is my html for my controllers

```
<div id="compare-table-controller"> 
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel-control left disabled " data-control="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel-control right " data-control="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ya7dL/3/)

Changed     `width: 700px` to     `width: 100%` You can change `left` value like width value (percentage value)